# How to resolve MATLAB trapz function error?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am working on an assignment that requires me to use the `trapz` function in MATLAB in order to evaluate an integral. I believe I have written the code correctly, but the program returns answers that are wildly incorrect.  I am attempting to find the integral of `e^(-x^2)` from `0` to `1`.

```
x = linspace(0,1,2000);
y = zeros(1,2000);
for iCnt = 1:2000
    y(iCnt) = e.^(-(x(iCnt)^2));
end

a = trapz(y);
disp(a);
```

This code currently returns

```
1.4929e+03
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: From the docs: "*trapz(Y) returns the approximate integral of Y via the trapezoidal method **with unit spacing***".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Could you elaborate? I read the doc but I don't understand what is meant by unit spacing

Comment: You probably need to divide by 2000 then, eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just specify also the `x` values:

```
x = linspace(0,1,2000);
y = exp(-x.^2);
a = trapz(x,y)

a =

    0.7468
```

**More details:**

- First of all, in MATLAB you can use vectors to avoid for-loops for performing operation on arrays (vectors). So the whole four lines of code

  y = zeros(1,2000);
  for iCnt = 1:2000
      y(iCnt) = exp(-(x(iCnt)^2));
  end

will be translated to one line:

```
y = exp(-x.^2)
```

- You defined `x = linspace(0,1,2000)` it means that you need to calculate the integral of the given function in range `[0 1]`. So there is a mistake in the way you calculate `y` which returns it to be in range `[1 2000]` and that is why you got the big number as the result.
- In addition, in MATLAB you should use `exp` there is not function as `e` in MATLAB.
- Also, if you plot the function in the range, you will see that the result makes sense because the whole page has an area of 1x1.

[image]

Comment: Sure, no problem!